# Como manipular Arrays Dinâmicos - PHP

Tags: php, array, loop, for, foreach

Estou tendo problemas para manipular 3 arrays individuais com indices dinâmicos que variam conforme entrada do usuario em um formulario em PHP, pois preciso passar os valores para uma ou mais instruções SQL para inserir no banco de dados dependendo da quantidade de índices nos arrays.

```
array(size=4)
   0 => string 'name' (length=4)
   1 => string 'email' (length=5)
   2 => string 'tel' (length=5)
   3 => string 'cod_var' (length=8)

array(size=4)
   0 => string 'Junior' (length=9)
   1 => string 'email@email.com' (length=26)
   2 => string '363' (length=3)
   3 => string '0' (length=1)

array(size=4)
   0 => string 'Junior Alpha' (length=8)
   1 => string 'email2@email.com' (length=25)
   2 => int 399
   3 => int 1
```

Não consegui fazer um foreach/for para que rode simultaneamente nos 3 arrays e traga os resultados em ordem sequencial para concatenar no SQL.

```
INSERT INTO dataInfo(type, old_value, new_value) VALUES ("name", "Junior", "Junior Alpha"); 
INSERT INTO dataInfo(type, old_value, new_value) VALUES ("email", "email@email.com", "email2@email.com");
INSERT INTO dataInfo(type, old_value, new_value) VALUES ("tel", "363", "399");
INSERT INTO dataInfo(type, old_value, new_value) VALUES ("cod_var", "0", "1");
```

Comment: Veja se essa abordagem não é mais adequada: https://ideone.com/xeDeUP .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tentou iterar sobre usando laço for?

```
for($i=0, $i < $array; $i++):
  // name
  $array[$i][0]..
  // email
  $array[$i][1]..
endfor;
```

Comment: Estava pensando de outra maneira, mas sua lógica é mais apropriada para meu cenário.

Fiz aqui e solucionou o problema.

Obrigado Rafael!

Comment: ao seu dispor bro!